# Setting rowHeight in UITableView in viewDidAppear

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

This is the current working code.

But this should be simpler, I guess.

If I use the commented code I get a wrong height size.

Anyone some suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[[self tableView]dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];
//      TableViewCell *cell = [[[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellClassName] autorelease];

     if (!cell)
        {
        NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
        // cell = [[[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellClassName] autorelease];
        }

    NSLog(@"cell height %f", cell.bounds.size.height);
    [[self tableView] setRowHeight:cell.bounds.size.height] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely simplify it. Just call your own implementation of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and use the cell that you get back from that, i.e.

```
UITableView *table = self.tableView;
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:table cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
[table setRowHeight:cell.bounds.size.height]
```

Voilà: no more duplicated code.

On another note, you might want to do this in `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear:` if your view controller is going to appear with animation. Doing it in `-viewDidAppear:` will cause the table’s row height to visibly jump when the view-presentation animation finishes.

Comment: Hi Noah,
Thank you.

About the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, thats very expensive even when I just return a precalculated value. I do use that in rows with cells which are dynamically in height.

About, you might want to do this in -viewDidLoad or -viewWillAppear, you are 100% right. In my case I have an animation part of the cell. Normally, I put it in one or the other depending of when the data is available. For the sample sake I should it put it in -viewDidLoad or -viewWillAppear.

Any other suggestions, and why does give the commented line a different height value as the one used now.